# How can I distinguish dynamic pages on a hook_menu?

Tags: 7, uri, routes

```
function mymodule_menu_local_tasks(&$variables) {
   if ( request_path == 'yadda') :
   ....
}
```

I can do that.. but the problem is I want to include this for the tabs on `user/$id/edit` and I'd rather not do regex or check the beginning and end of the string...

Is there some way I can pull a variable that relates to that specific page type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell if you're on a node page with `menu_get_object()`, but other than that it's difficult. `menu_get_object()` can return other objects than a node, but you need to know the type of entity before you call it (not much help in your situation). There's no generic solution that I know of in Drupal 7.

There is the [`drupal_match_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_match_path/7) function though, which you can use with wildcards, e.g.

```
if (drupal_match_path(request_path(), 'user/*/edit')) {
  // On a user edit page
}
```

Comment: great! that seems to be doing the trick thank you.